# Selenium findElement in the another findElement

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

For example, I have an element1 which I can find after I find element2, like this:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath2")).findElement(By.xpath("//xpath1")).click();
```

I want to use PageObjectModel and annotations @FindBy, like these:

```java
@FindBy(xpath = "//xpath1")
private WebElement element1;

@FindBy(xpath = "//xpath2")
private WebElement element2;
```

The problem: I don't know how to rewrite the code, this doesn't work:

```java
element2.element1.click();
```

Comment: Are you trying to find element 2 by a relative xpath from element 1? It's hard to tell, because both xpaths look like absolute paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@FindBy(xpath = ".//xpath1")
private WebElement element1;

@FindBy(xpath = ".//xpath2//xpath1")
private WebElement element2;
```

Use

```
element2.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a couple of solutions.

The first, if you want to use 2 FindBys is:

```
@FindBys({@FindBy(xpath = "//xpath2"),
       @FindBy(xpath = "//xpath1")})
```

The second is to put the second xpath code in an explicit findElement function

```
element1.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath1")).click();
```

Finally, you can probably combine the first xpath and the second into a single xpath

```
@FindBy(xpath="//xpath2//xpath1")
```

However, I imagine that you probably are asking this because you have a single element that you like to find lots of other elements within.  That, unfortunately, is not possible with strictly @FindBy.

Comment: You are trying to combine css selector and xpath :P That won't work